# Facebook FQL: Difference between status table and stream table?

Tags: stream, facebook-fql, status

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between the status table and the stream table?

I am querying my own posts using the graph explorer and I find some status updates appear only in the status table, and others appear in both the stream and status table.  When I go to my own Timeline I can see posts from both tables.

What is going on here? Why are some in the posts table only, but appear on my Timeline?!

I am trying to find a list of all my posts that are publicly visible, and it seems to do this I need to query both tables and end up with some duplicates.  Is there a better way?

Here is an example:

```
    graph.facebook.com/10150680671412355

{
  "id": "10150680671412355", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Alan Byrne", 
    "id": "509517354"
  }, 
  "message": "Beans on toast.", 
  "updated_time": "2012-03-14T10:53:01+0000", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "xxxxx", 
        "name": "xxxx"
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10150680671412355/likes?method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&callback=___GraphExplorerAsyncCallback___&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAPjaO9gCyMZA2TT5hRE7iEkgmksfpNneFdtshFDfp0oM3hiX6I57vUkzGZAyXW5c9YaM1WQFUxt2zTZCden7zTAlbMSDAZDZD&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=100001368900242"
    }
  }, 
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "10150680671412355_31516486", 
        "from": {
          "name": "xxxxx", 
          "id": "xxxxx"
        }, 
        "message": "Peasant. Baked beans on the other hand...", 
        "can_remove": true, 
        "created_time": "2012-03-14T11:20:35+0000"
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10150680671412355/comments?method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&callback=___GraphExplorerAsyncCallback___&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAPjaO9gCyMZA2TT5hRE7iEkgmksfpNneFdtshFDfp0oM3hiX6I57vUkzGZAyXW5c9YaM1WQFUxt2zTZCden7zTAlbMSDAZDZD&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=10150680671412355_31516486"
    }
  }, 
  "type": "status"
}
```

Yet, when I scan for posts on the stream on that same day, this one does not come back

```
fql?q=select message,post_id,created_time from stream where source_id=509517354 and created_time > 1331596800 and created_time < 1331856000

{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150680640782355", 
      "created_time": 1331720877
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150680632467355", 
      "created_time": 1331720499
    }, 
    {
      "message": "MY COMPUTER DOES NOT HAVE VIRUSES! STOP CALLING ME! ARGH!", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150680618357355", 
      "created_time": 1331719866
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150680602327355", 
      "created_time": 1331719906
    }, 
    {
      "message": "I did it!", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150680491832355", 
      "created_time": 1331716355
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150680446052355", 
      "created_time": 1331714440
    }, 
    {
      "message": "It got to Australia.\n", 
      "post_id": "509517354_365689393454249", 
      "created_time": 1331679835
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_107999992664739", 
      "created_time": 1331677643
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150678888762355", 
      "created_time": 1331671872
    }, 
    {
      "message": "Booooo", 
      "post_id": "509517354_268316116580687", 
      "created_time": 1331632096
    }, 
    {
      "message": "'spose I should wander into the office...", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150678259167355", 
      "created_time": 1331625013
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150678258862355", 
      "created_time": 1331624991
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150678257547355", 
      "created_time": 1331624907
    }, 
    {
      "message": "", 
      "post_id": "509517354_10150678250602355", 
      "created_time": 1331631742
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The stream contains posts of various types - links, checkins, photos *and* status updates.

The status table only contains status updates - text with no additional links, photos etc.

If you're hoping to find the content similar to the timeline, you'll want to use the stream table.

Comment: Hi Tom. The issue is that if I query the stream table I don't get all the results that are on the timeline.  There are items in the posts table that do not appear in the stream table, yet are on my timeline.  Is this normal?

Comment: Hmm. What style of story are you missing? Regular, simple, shared posts? Or more complex stories? [This migration](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/) might be related.

Comment: It's just a normal post.  See edit above for more information